# Autodesk Forge Webhooks with multiple apps

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-webhooks

I'm developing integrations using Autodesk Forge Webhooks API, but find that only one webhook can be added to a root folder by the account.

Even when I create another app (Client ID, secret pair) and use it to retrieve another access token, I still see the same webhooks and can delete or update them.

Seems it doesn't matter which app the access token was authorized from, as long as it represents the same account, they share the same webhooks and apply the limit of only one hook on one root folder.

My question is, is this design intentional? It seems problematic because one account owner might connect his/her account to different applications (represented by different Client ID & secret pairs). And more than one of the applications might utilize webhooks. The current behavior I observed could results in different apps conflicting or overwriting each others' webhooks.

My test account is A360 personal btw, I don't have a A360 team nor BIM360 account so not sure whether they behave differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, this is by design. Thanks for your feedback and description, we're looking into improving it.